# How to clear a function with subscript?

Tags: functions, subscript, clear

How to clear a function like

```
Subscript[f, n_][x_] := x f[x - 1] + n;
```

`ClearAll[f]` didn't work.

Comment: inb4 the "never use Subscripts" crowd  -- `?? Subscript` will reveal that your function is actually defined as a `SubValue` of `Subscript`, which is why `ClearAll[f]` didn't work.  Use `Subscript[f, n_][x_] =.` to clear it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Subscript[f, n_][x_] := x f[x - 1] + n;
Subscript[f, n][x]
Clear[Subscript]
Subscript[f, n][x]
```